# Trying to have 2 forms pass to 2 different controllers from one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller

I have 2 forms in one view one is displayed if the user is a moderator and the other if it is a normal user and they both send the information to 2 different controllers. My problem is that if its a normal user, the form that is displayed for them uses the wrong controller.

Here is the coding

categories/new.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.mod_of_game? @guide %>

 <%= form_for([@guide, @category], url: guide_categories_path) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name, "Category name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.submit "Next"  %>
<% end %>

<% else %>


<%= form_for([@guide, @check_category], url: check_category_post_path) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

 <%= f.label :name, "Category name" %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>

 <%= f.submit "Next"  %>
<% end %>


<% end %>
```

Categories controller

```
before_action :mod_checker, only: [:create]

 def new
    @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
    @category = Guide.friendly.find(@guide.id).categories.new
    @check_category = CheckCategory.new
end


 def create
 @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
   @category = Guide.friendly.find(@guide.id).categories.new(category_params)

 if ((@category.save) && (current_user.mod_of_game? @guide))

  flash[:info] = "guide category added succesfully!"
  redirect_to @guide
  else

   render 'new'

   end
    end

private

def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name)
end

 def mod_checker
 @guide = Guide.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
 unless current_user.mod_of_game? @guide
  flash[:danger] = "Sorry something went wrong!"
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

check_categories controller

```
def new
    end

def create
if @check_category.save

            flash[:info] = "Game category added successfully. A mod will apporve it shortly."
          redirect_to @guide

   else
   render 'new'
   end

    end

private


def check_category_params
    params.require(:check_category).permit(:name)
end
```

and the routes

```
resources :guides do
   resources :categories,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end

  resources :check_categories,     only: [:new, :edit, :update]

  match 'guides/:guide_id/categories/' => 'check_categories#create', :via => :post, as: :check_category_post
```

sorry the coding is a bit messy, the 4 spaces to put it in a code block was spacing my coding weird.

When i have a non moderator user submit the form, the before action in the categories controller is run and I'm redirected to the homepage. I don't know why it does this because the submit path should go to the check_categories controller for non moderator users, the check_categories controller doesn't have the before filter.

Why does it use the before filter in the controller I'm not using for that form? How can I fix it?

Building this app to learn rails better. So I can only assume lack of rails knowledge is causing me to do something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Bad practice to have two forms with identical code (apart from the `path`) - goes against [DRY `Don't Repeat Yourself`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Getting_Started/Don%C2%B4t_repeat_yourself).

As mentioned by `@Akash`, this sounds like a job for [authorization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

Further, it also denotes that you have issues with the underlying structure of your code. Specifically, you have an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) with `CheckCategory` (you can put it all into the `Category` model):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :guides do
   resources :categories, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update] do
      patch :approve, on: :member
   end
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_action :set_guide

    def new
        @category = current_user.categories.new
        flash[:notice] = "Since you are not a moderator, this will have to be approved." unless current_user.mod_of_game? @guide
    end

    def create
        @category = current_user.categories.new category_params
        @category.guide = @guide
        @category.save
    end

    def approve
        @category = @guide.categories.find params[:id]
        @category.approve
    end

    private

    def set_guide
        @guide = Guide.find params[:guide_id]
    end
end

#app/views/categories/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@guide, @category] do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

   <%= f.label :name, "Category name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.submit "Next"  %>
<% end %>
```

The above will solve most of your structural issues.

--

To fix the authorization issue, you'll be best denoting whether the category is "approved" in the model:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum status: [:pending, :approved]

   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :guide
   validates  :user, :guide presence: true
   before_create :set_status

   def approve
      self.update status: "approved"
   end

   private

   def set_status
      self[:status] = "approved" if self.user.mod_of_game? self.guide
   end
end
```

--

If I understand correctly, you want to allow anyone to create a category, but none-mods are to have their categories "checked" by a moderator.

The code above should implement this for you.

You will need to add a gem such as <s>`CanCan`</s> [`CanCanCan`](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to implement some authorization:

```
#app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <%= link_to "Approve", guide_category_approve_path(@guide, category) if category.waiting? && can? :update, Category %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Ive looked at CanCanCan and pundit in the past but they look like they are more for a moderator that can moderate all of something e.g. all posts. I need it so only moderators of categories can moderate whats in that category. I have this setup so the info goes to a separate db to be approved by a mod and if approved it gets moved to the main db to be displayed. plus this way the db is a bit faster displaying info by not having to check if every bit of info is approved first.

Comment: And I will also have version control. If a normal user edits information it needs to be approved by a mod first, CanCanCan doesn't have that kind of flexibility it would need to create 2 of the same record in the db, on approved and one not, and the unapproved would need to replace the other once its approved having 2 db makes this much easier and more controllable.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Cancan" Gem and give authorization